# percentile discrepancy between bigquery trigrams and ngrams viewer?

Tags: google-bigquery

can someone please help explain what appears to be a discrepancy between bigquery trigrams and ngrams viewer percentile values (seems different for any given trigram but here is one specific example corroborated by the post https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bigquery-discuss/OT_W0ayVSvg)?

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT cell.value, cell.volume_fraction
FROM [bigquery-public-data:samples.trigrams] 
WHERE ngram = "of these dinosaurs" AND cell.value = "1888"),
(SELECT cell.value, cell.volume_fraction
FROM [bigquery-public-data:samples.trigrams] 
WHERE ngram = "of these dinosaurs" AND cell.value = "1890")
```

https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/savedquery/977440528149:1539bcaba54144d3bd9920c55ede72b9

1890    1.6196954972465177E-4
1888    1.6196954972465177E-4

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=of+these+dinosaurs&year_start=1888&year_end=1890&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cof%20these%20dinosaurs%3B%2Cc0

1890 0.0000001270%
1888 0.0000001256%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such discrepancy is explained because you are using two different datasets. BigQuery trigrams reads the data from a **sample** dataset that contain certain books and might have been modified for testing purposes. The [official description](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sample-tables) is:

> Contains English language trigrams from a sample of works published
>   between 1520 and 2008.

Google Books is nowadays continuously updated based on the `Partner Program` and `Library Project` as you can see [here](https://www.google.com/intl/en/googlebooks/about/index.html).

So you are comparing a query in a static demonstration 258GB dataset to Google Books platform.